# How to get a random item from plist based on a criteria

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

I got a plist with this format

```
 <plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>category</key>
        <string>desert</string>
        <key>numberOfPerson</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>recipeImage</key>
        <string>X78a.jpg</string>
        <key>time</key>
        <string>15 min</string>
        <key>recipeName</key>
        <string>Puding</string>
        <key>recipeDetail</key>
```

i read it into a NSArray and can use them pretty good for now.One of the variables in my plist is category. I need to get a random item for each category( there are 3 in total). How can i make this happen?

```
  NSArray *newArray = [NSArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in self.content)
    if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"category"] isEqualToString:filterInput])
        [array addObject:dictionary];
self.filteredContent = array;
```

this is what i used to get all items from a specific category but how can i select one from each category and show them in cells??

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a random number for each category between 0 (inclusive) and the length of the array for that category (exclusive). Then, grab that item.

Your code:

```
NSArray *newArray = [NSArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in self.content) {
    if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"category"] isEqualToString:filterInput]) {
        [array addObject:dictionary];
    }
}
```

Grab a random item:

```
int randomNumber = arc4random_uniform([array count]);
NSString *randomItem = [array objectAtIndex:randomNumber];
```

Comment: oh how did i miss that. So simple yet so clever.Thank you.